# How to mock jdbcTemplate.execute(callableStatementCreator, callableStatementCallback);

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to mock (Spring boot, JUnit, Oracle)

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(CallableStatementCreator, CallableStatementCallback);

public class ExceptionTest
{
  @Autowired
  private SecurityDAOImpl securityDAOImplMock;

  @Mock
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate resetJdbcTemplate;

  @Before
  public void init() throws Exception
  {
    securityDAOImplMock = spy(new SecurityDAOImpl());
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Test(expected = SecurityDAOException.class)
  public void testUpdateProfileException()
  {
    DataAccessException dataAccessException = new DataAccessException("Mock Exception",
        new Exception("Mocked DataAccessException"))
    {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    };
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(securityDAOImplMock, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);
    doThrow(dataAccessException).when(jdbcTemplate).execute(any(), any());
    securityDAOImplMock.isTooManyFailedAttempt("", 7, "", "");
  }

  @After
  public void reset()
  {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(securityDAOImplMock, "jdbcTemplate", resetJdbcTemplate);
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following compile time exception:

```
The method execute(PreparedStatementCreator, PreparedStatementCallback<Object>) is ambiguous for the type
```

on this line

```
doThrow(securityDAOException).when(jdbcTemplate).execute(any(), any());
```

How to mock jdbcTemplate.execute(callableStatementCreator, callableStatementCallback).How to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `JdbcTemplate.execute()` is [overloaded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/).

So when you mock it using matcher `any()` the compiler simply does not know which method you actually mean and throws an error.

To fix that supply a class in the matcher to resolve this ambiguity.

For example, if you want to mock

```java
JdbcTemplate.execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)
```

use

```java
doThrow(securityDAOException).when(jdbcTemplate).execute(any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), any(PreparedStatementCallback.class));
```

Comment: Thank you @Pavel. I was able to make it work by adding doThrow(dataAccessException).when(jdbcTemplate).execute(any(CallableStatementCreator.class),
        any(CallableStatementCallback.class));